# Same Code wrapping for different dao methods

Tags: java, hibernate, appfuse

I was going through the hibernate tutorial and noticed that in every dao you have to get session,begin transaction.Perform all operations and then commit

```
private void createAndStoreEvent(String title, Date theDate) {
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
        session.beginTransaction();

        //Perform operations...

        session.getTransaction().commit();
    }
```

Then i have noticed in a framework called Appfuse which uses hibernate have dao methods as shown below.I dont see the begintransaction and commit

```
    public List<Person> findByLastName(String lastName) {
    //begintransaction
        return getHibernateTemplate().find("from Person where lastName=?", lastName);
    //Commit
    }
```

I wonder how appfuse is wrapping up the dao operations with session.beginTransaction() and session.getTransaction().commit();

By using this technique the programmer doesn't have to bother about hibernate transaction stuff.I want it in such a a way that even if dao methods are overridden the transaction wrapper code should automatically come.
I have tried passing dao to a decorator class and wrapping the dao method call inside decorator class.But since the dao interface methods will change,the idea dint worked.How exactly we can achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how AppFuse is doing it, but a very common way of introducing transaction management into the service layer of an application is by using Aspect Oriented Programming. If you're using the Spring Framework, [this](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/aop.html) (from the manual) is a good reference.

Answer (score 1):

[`HibernateTemplate`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/classic-spring.html#orm-hibernate-template) is part of Spring. You can read more about it at this link. But starting with Spring 3.0, it's considered to be deprecated in favor of [declarative transaction management](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/orm.html#orm-hibernate-tx-declarative).